# Get Python and C++ stack trace at once in VS Code

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am trying to debug Python code in VS code, and stack trace looks like this:

```
method3
method2
method1
```

If I look to sources: method1 calls some 'built-in method of Pycapsule object', and this 'built-in method' calls Python method2.
Also, method2 calls method3 through another 'built-in method of Pycapsule object'.

I want to get full stack trace including c++ parts at once in VS code GUI. Is it possible?

Comment: FYI: [Debugging Mixed Python C++ code in Visual Studio Code](https://gist.github.com/kongdd/f49fabdbf0af20ec7fd6b4f8cd1f450d)

Answer (score 0):

The [Python C++ debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug) extension works pretty well. It automates the process of starting the Python debugger, and then attaching the C++ debugger. You don't get a single stack trace; rather have have two debuggers running at the same time, so you have two different stack traces.

[image]

There is also a dropdown in the floating debugger toolbar to choose the debugger you're interested in.

When the extension doesn't work, you have to do it manually. I.e., start Python debugger, stopping on a breakpoint (or setting `stopAtEntry` to `true` in launch.json). Then attach the C++ debugger, adding a suitable configuration in launch.json for this if you don't have one already. Unfortunately, there are multiple matches if you just type "python" into the search box. By a process of trial and error / seeing into which process my python module is loaded, I found that "debugpy -" works on linux and ";debugpy" on Windows.